# Parse with Windows Phone 8 Universal Apps

Tags: exception, windows-phone-8, parse-platform, win-universal-app

I have a Windows 8.1 Universal app that I am using with Parse. I have downloaded the latest .NET libraries for Parse and included the Parse.dll and ParseWindows.dll in the Windows 8 project. The app works just fine with them.

I then include the Parse.dll and parsePhone.dll in the Windows Phone app. When the phone app runs, I get a `FileNotFound` exception when the `ParseClient.initialize` method is called. The method is in a static class within my Shared library, and is used by both projects. It works fine in the Windows 8 app, but throws the exception in the Windows Phone app.

This is the method that gets called, with the keys redacted.

```
public static class ParseCloudService
{
    public static void InitializeParseCloudService()
    {
        try
        {
            ParseClient.Initialize("AppIdGoesHere", ".NETKey");
        }
        catch(ParseException)
        {
            throw;
        }
    }
}
```

Has anyone else ran in to this? Is there something that I'm supposed to be adding to the Windows Phone 8.1 app that the Parse library expects? Again, this is in a Universal app, and not a standard Windows Phone app project (previous posts I've made this gets confused).

Another interesting thing, is that even though I have this wrapped in a try/catch, the exception goes thrown within the Intialize() method, and never gets caught by my try/catch. If I set a break-point in my catch, the breakpoint never gets hit. It throws within Initialize(), then immediately breaks within app.g.i.cs file.

```
Could not load file or assembly 'System.Windows, Version=2.0.6.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
```

and this is the stack trace:

```
   at Parse.PlatformHooks.SettingsWrapper..ctor()
   at Parse.PlatformHooks.SettingsWrapper.get_Wrapper()
   at Parse.PlatformHooks.get_ApplicationSettings()
   at Parse.ParseClient.get_ApplicationSettings()
   at Parse.ParseClient.get_InstallationId()
   at Parse.ParseClient.Initialize(String applicationId, String dotnetKey)
   at Actions.Services.ParseCloud.ParseCloudService.InitializeParseCloudService()
   at Actions.Services.ParseCloud.ParseCloudUserService..ctor()
   at lambda_method(Closure , IBuilderContext )
   at Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder2.DynamicBuildPlanGenerationContext.<>c__DisplayClass1.<GetBuildMethod>b__0(IBuilderContext context)
   at Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder2.DynamicMethodBuildPlan.BuildUp(IBuilderContext context)
   at Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder2.BuildPlanStrategy.PreBuildUp(IBuilderContext context)
   at Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder2.StrategyChain.ExecuteBuildUp(IBuilderContext context)
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Parse .NET SDK will not be updated to support Windows Phone 8.1.

Source: https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/327073484113608/

Comment: THanks Izaac, I had actually responded to that post the day before your answer on here. I ended up just writing two service layers for the app, one using the SDK for WinRT and one using the Rest API for the phone. It ended working out just fine in the end